# Splice issue when all array values are same

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have created an empty array that I use to loop through to dynamically add and remove text-boxes on my form.

```
mobiles: Array<string> = [];

<ng-container *ngFor="let mobile of mobiles; index as i">
// Code
</ng-container>
```

Outside the loop, I have a button to add a new text-box.

```
<button (click)="addElement()">
</button>
```

And I have a button inside the loop to remove the specific text-box, based on the index.

```
<button (click)="removeElement(i)">
</button>
```

The `addElement()` function simply pushes an empty value to the end of the array.

```
this.mobiles.push('');
```

While the `removeElement(index)` function removes the index from the array.

```
if (index in this.mobiles) {
    this.mobiles.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The issue with this code is that since all values on my array are the same (empty), `splice()` is not removing the element at the specified index but rather the last element in the array. And as such, it's also removing the last text-box instead of the one I click.

I tested pushing non-empty values in my array but the result is still the same. It only works correctly if I push distinct values, for example:

```
this.mobiles.push(this.mobiles.length);
```

I do not want to use this method however, since I plan to fill this array with actual phone numbers.

Is there any alternative?

My Angular version is 7.2.15.

Thank you!

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phgo61

Comment: Your method seems perfect if you have implemented the function correctly. The splice function will only remove the specified index and I believe the issue is somewhere else. Can you provide a demo with the usecase?

Comment: Here you go @Arcteezy: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phgo61. It's working as I mentioned above, the last element is removed instead of the one I click.

Comment: It is removing the correct position in the array, however as you are not saving the input strings to the collection it seems like you are removing from the bottom but you are not.

Comment: See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cwqyjf

Comment: @joelgullander This is only working correctly because you're adding distinct values in the array. And I am actively trying to avoid doing that, as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround for that problem is to wrap each value in an object. The value of each item in the `ngFor` loop will then be the reference of the object. Since these references are all different, the targeted item will be deleted, as intended.

Using this interface:

```
interface Phone {
  phoneNumber?: string;
}
```

You can define an array of `Phone` objects:

```
mobiles: Array<Phone> = [];

addElement() {
  this.mobiles.push({});
}

removeElement(index) {
  this.mobiles.splice(index, 1);
}

get phoneNumbers() {
  return this.mobiles.map(x => x.phoneNumber);
}
```

and edit the `phoneNumber` property in the template:

```html
<button (click)="addElement()">Add phone</button>
<ng-container *ngFor="let mobile of mobiles; index as i;">
  <div>
    <input [(ngModel)]="mobile.phoneNumber" />
    <button (click)="removeElement(i)">Remove element</button>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wscxwt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: This is perfect since I can also store country phone codes separately if I want/need to. Excellent answer, thanks a lot!